# How to link syscall traces to Java source code?

Tags: java, system-calls, strace

I'm using `strace` in Linux to get the system call traces of a Java program. However, I don't know how to link the trace to the source code (which piece of code produce corresponding trace).

I use `-k` option but it seems not help in Java (which is useful for C and C++ program). I can only link the traces to `.so` file.

```
mmap(0x7fcd168a9000, 12288, PROT_NONE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS|MAP_NORESERVE, -1, 0) = 0x7fcd168a9000
 > /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.23.so(mmap64+0x3a) [0x1017ba]
 > /home/xxxxxx/Desktop/jdk1.8.0_271/jre/lib/amd64/server/libjvm.so(os::pd_uncommit_memory(char*, unsigned long)+0x19) [0x919799]
 > /home/xxxxxx/Desktop/jdk1.8.0_271/jre/lib/amd64/server/libjvm.so(os::uncommit_memory(char*, unsigned long)+0x8b) [0x91016b]
 > /home/xxxxxx/Desktop/jdk1.8.0_271/jre/lib/amd64/server/libjvm.so(JavaThread::exit(bool, JavaThread::ExitType)+0xb99) [0xa87029]
 > /home/xxxxxx/Desktop/jdk1.8.0_271/jre/lib/amd64/server/libjvm.so(JavaThread::thread_main_inner()+0x27) [0xa87297]
 > /home/xxxxxx/Desktop/jdk1.8.0_271/jre/lib/amd64/server/libjvm.so(JavaThread::run()+0x2d1) [0xa87651]
 > /home/xxxxxx/Desktop/jdk1.8.0_271/jre/lib/amd64/server/libjvm.so(java_start(Thread*)+0x102) [0x915cd2]
 > /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread-2.23.so(start_thread+0xca) [0x76ba]
 > /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.23.so(clone+0x6d) [0x10751d]
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, [QUIT], NULL, 8) = 0
 > /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread-2.23.so(pthread_sigmask+0x2f) [0xe49f]
 > /home/xxxxxx/Desktop/jdk1.8.0_271/jre/lib/amd64/server/libjvm.so(os::free_thread(OSThread*)+0xb4) [0x916134]
 > /home/xxxxxx/Desktop/jdk1.8.0_271/jre/lib/amd64/server/libjvm.so(Thread::~Thread()+0x19a) [0xa8395a]
 > /home/xxxxxx/Desktop/jdk1.8.0_271/jre/lib/amd64/server/libjvm.so(JavaThread::~JavaThread()+0x11) [0xa83d11]
 > /home/xxxxxx/Desktop/jdk1.8.0_271/jre/lib/amd64/server/libjvm.so(JavaThread::thread_main_inner()+0x35) [0xa872a5]
 > /home/xxxxxx/Desktop/jdk1.8.0_271/jre/lib/amd64/server/libjvm.so(JavaThread::run()+0x2d1) [0xa87651]
 > /home/xxxxxx/Desktop/jdk1.8.0_271/jre/lib/amd64/server/libjvm.so(java_start(Thread*)+0x102) [0x915cd2]
 > /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread-2.23.so(start_thread+0xca) [0x76ba]
 > /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.23.so(clone+0x6d) [0x10751d]
```

How can I solve this?